# How do I detect if two dates straddle a weekend?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11

### Problem

**Given two datetimes, `dt0` and `dt1` (could be out of order), what is an algorithm which can determine if there is at least 24 hours worth of weekend (SAT, SUN) between the two dates?**

Assume that there is a `dayofweek()` function that returns 0 for SUN, 1 for MON, etc...

Note: the problem is easy to visualize geometrically in terms of line segments, but the calculation eludes me for the moment.

### Solution

The solution below will work for UTC, but it will fail for DST.

- `weekdayno()` implementation not included: SUN==0, MON==1, etc...
- `isWeekday()` is also not shown, but is trivial to implement once you have `dayofweek()`
- binary `operator-()` implementation also not shown, but we simply convert both instances to UNIX-time (no. of secs since Epoch) and take the difference to yield the number of seconds between two `DateTime`s
- `hh()` `mm()` `ss()` are just const accessors for returning hours, minutes, and seconds, respectively

**James McNellis** is right on the mark concerning DST.

*Getting this code to work for the general DST case is non-trivial: need to add tz and anywhere you do any kind of date arithmetic requires careful consideration.  Additional unit tests will be needed.*

### Lessons Learned

- Query stackoverflow for various ways to look at a problem.
- You can never have too many unit tests:  need them to flush out weird edge cases
- Use visualization, if possible, to look at a problem
- What appears to be a trivial problem can actually be a bit tricky when you look at the details (eg DST).
- Keep the solution **as simple as possible** because your code will very likely change: in order to fix for bugs/new test cases or in order to add new features (eg make it work for DST).  Keep it as readable and easy to understand as possible: prefer algorithms over switch/cases.
- Be brave and try things out: keep hammering at the solution until something works comes about.  Use unit-tests so you can continuously refactor.  It takes a lot of work to write simple code, but in the end, it's worth it.

### Conclusion

The current solution is sufficient for my purposes (I will use UTC to avoid DST problems).  I will select **holygeek**'s Answer for his suggestion that I draw some ASCII art.  In this case, doing so has helped me come up with an algorithm that is easy-to-understand and really, as simple as I can possibly make it.  Thanks to all for contributing to the analysis of this problem.

```
static const size_t ONEDAYINSECS = (24 * 60 * 60); 

DateTime
DateTime::nextSatMorning() const
{
  // 0 is SUN, 6 is SAT
  return *this + (6 - weekdayno()) * ONEDAYINSECS -
    (((hh() * 60) + mm())*60 + ss());
}

DateTime 
DateTime::previousSunNight() const
{
  return *this - ((weekdayno() - 1 + 7)%7) * ONEDAYINSECS -
    (((hh() * 60) + mm())*60 + ss());
}

bool
DateTime::straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( const DateTime& newDt ) const
{
  const DateTime& t0 = min( *this, newDt );
  const DateTime& t1 = max( *this, newDt );
  
  // ------------------------------------
  //
  // <--+--F--+--S--+--S--+--M--+-->
  //    t0    ^           ^    t1
  //    +---->+           +<----|
  //          |           |
  //          +<--nSecs-->+
  //        edge0       edge1
  //
  // ------------------------------------

  DateTime edge0 = t0.isWeekday() ? t0.nextSatMorning()   : t0;                       
  DateTime edge1 = t1.isWeekday() ? t1.previousSunNight() : t1;
                   
  return (edge1 - edge0) > ONEDAYINSECS;
}
```

**John Leidegren** asked for my unit tests so here there are (using googletest)
Note that they pass for the non-DST cases above (running for UTC) - I expect the current implementation to fail for DST cases (haven't added them to the test cases below yet).

```
TEST( Test_DateTime, tryNextSatMorning )
{
  DateTime mon{     20010108, 81315 };
  DateTime exp_sat{ 20010113, 0ul   };

  EXPECT_EQ( exp_sat, mon.nextSatMorning() );
}

TEST( Test_DateTime, tryPrevSunNight )
{
  DateTime tue{      20010109, 81315 };
  DateTime exp_sun1{ 20010108, 0ul   };

  EXPECT_EQ( exp_sun1, tue.previousSunNight() );

  DateTime sun{      20010107, 81315 };
  DateTime exp_sun2{ 20010101, 0ul   };

  EXPECT_EQ( exp_sun2, sun.previousSunNight() );
}

TEST( Test_DateTime, straddlesWeekend )
{
  DateTime fri{ 20010105, 163125 };
  DateTime sat{ 20010106, 101515 };
  DateTime sun{ 20010107, 201521 };
  DateTime mon{ 20010108,  81315 };
  DateTime tue{ 20010109,  81315 };

  EXPECT_FALSE( fri.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( sat ));
  EXPECT_TRUE(  fri.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( sun ));
  EXPECT_TRUE(  fri.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( mon ));
  EXPECT_TRUE(  sat.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( sun ));
  EXPECT_TRUE(  sat.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( mon ));
  EXPECT_FALSE( sun.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( mon ));
  EXPECT_TRUE(  fri.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( tue ));
  EXPECT_FALSE( sun.straddles_24HofWeekend_OrMore( tue ));
}
```

Comment: no - it's part of a library I am building

Comment: Without any constraints, it would be quite tedious to write this from scratch, since one would have to account for daylight savings time in various time zones and locations, among other calendar irregularities.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis +1 for pointing out DST issues: I will watch out for them once I get the basic algorithm in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This diagram may help:

```
  SAT       SUN
|---------|---------|
a---------b
 a---------b
 ...
          a---------b
```

Comment: +1 aye - visualization will definitely help: actually you gave me a cheap trick - if I add 24 hours to a and it's less than b, I'm done (with a little adjustment depending on where a is)... ...will think a bit more - tyvm!

Comment: I have picked holygeek's Answer for his contribution (using ASCII art for visualizing a problem) to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The silliest way I can think of solving this is: copy the smaller datetime value, continuously add to it until it's either larger than the other datetime value (the bigger one) or dayofweek() doesn't equal 0 or 7 any more. Then check if the total value of time you added is less than 24 hours.

A slightly less silly way would be to check its a weekend, add 24 hours of time and then check once to make sure its a weekend and still less than the second datetime.

Daylight savings shouldn't really come into play as long as your function to find what day it is works.

Comment: that crossed my mind, too, but I'm dealing with datetimes, not just dates so it's a little trickier - another possibility is, if I can detected all the boundaries between weekdays and weekends that lie within t0 and t1 and cut up my time line into weekday, weekend, weekday, weekend, weekday, weekend, etc... then, I can calculate the length of weekday segments and the length of weekend segments.  I think this may be a little closer...

Comment: your datetime should just be a big value such as the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970. or something as equally confusing if you are making it up yourself.

Comment: how I implement datetime internally should not make a difference here.  however, dst is an issue - for example, it is possible for for two dates to be SAT 9AM and SUN 9AM, and yet they could be only 23 hours apart or as much as 25 hours apart - so any kind of datetime arithmetic can get tricky - one way around this is to require everything to be UTC or in a time-zone where there is no DST, but that's a bit of a cop out

Answer (score 1):

Approach it in a structured manner: What are some of the simple/edge cases? What is the average case?

Simple cases I can think of off the top of my head (note, since you've already forced `t0` to be the lower value, I'm assuming that below):

1. If `t1 - t0` is less than 1 day, return false
2. If `t1 - t0` is >= 6 days, return true (there's ALWAYS 24 hours of weekend time in any given 6 day block, even if you start on a Sunday).

Then we take dayofweek() for both `t0` and `t1`, and do some checks (this is the average case). We can be extra cheap here now because we *know* `t0` is only up to 5 days earlier than `t1`.

*Edit:* Removed my conditions because there were nasty little edge cases I wasn't considering. Anyway, the solution I recommended is still viable, I just won't do it here.

Comment: PS: If I've missed a case or got one wrong, rather than downvoting please allow me to correct it first :)

Comment: when thinking about this problem, I flip-flop between coming up with a general solution and breaking down all the possibilities like you have done - it definitely seems possible to "infer" if you've broken 24 hours worth, but then you have all these if/else statements which may be error-prone unless you are extremely careful...

Comment: On the plus side though, the code's more immediately clear in what it is doing and less computationally intensive (you do one initial subtractions and there are no additions, just comparisons).

Comment: Actually, if you go about it this way you'll find that your final solutions contains far less if/else statements. And the more you iterate over your solution the less convoluted it typically becomes. And eventually you should be able to identify common abstractions that you can build all your other functions on top of. At that point most of your calculations should be simple and straight forward. That's when you know you've done a good job. I think this is what @darvids0n is on to.

Comment: You might also find it helpful to go about it the other way, that's to say, try to write test cases for the code. This is a way to work through the problem from a different angle and you don't need to go all TDD to get something useful out of it.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I already have a bunch of TDD cases that I need to pass ;^)  Check the updated algorithm in the OP: it is easier to understand/less bug prone, if I can figure out how to do those last two calcs: still thinking.

Comment: Would like to share your test cases as well? It would be helpful to understand exactly that conditions your trying to assert.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren - sure, I will post them at the end, after we come to a solution, but the OP essentially describes the problem - given any two datetimes, I want to determine if they straddle at least 24 hours worth of weekend.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren - ok, I've pushed this solution as far as I need for my project.  The OP has been edited to reflect the latest changes.  Thx to all for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

This site calculates business days in C#, does that help? http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/7156.aspx

Comment: ty, but those solutions may be more complex than what I'm looking for - since I have to edit their solutions to fit my question, their solutions may be slightly too far off-edge for me to shoe-horn into this solution.